# SICP cons-stream

Tags: scheme, sicp, cons

regarding to SICP 3.5

my own implementation is as following

```
(define (delay exp) (lambda () exp))

(define (force delayed-obj)
  (delayed-obj))

(define (cons-stream a b) (cons a (delay b)))

(define (stream-car stream) (car stream))


(define (stream-cdr stream) (force (cdr stream)))

(define (take n stream) 
  (if (= n 0)
      (print "0")
      (begin (take (- n 1) (stream-cdr stream))
             (print n))))

(define (make-stream-enum-interval low high)
  (if (> low high)
      '()
      (begin (print low) (cons-stream low (make-stream-enum-interval (+ low 1) high)))))
```

actually I found it's not really delayed.
when I execute (define range-10-to-100 (make-stream-enum-interval 10 100)). I expect to see only 10 is print in the console. while it's 10.....100

is there anything wrong with my code?
Or, if print 10...100 is necessary, then we can say the structure is
    (cons 10 (delay 
        cons 11 (delay
            cons 12 (delay
                ....100)))
if so, then we need more memory?

Comment: You can also use lips macros `(define-macro (delay . exp) \`(lambda () ,@exp))`

Answer (score 9):

Scheme uses [eager evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eager_evaluation). That means that all arguments to a function call are evaluated before the function is entered. Thus, since your `delay` was a function, expressions passed to `delay` get evaluated first.

To get around this, make `delay` a macro, as does anything that uses it (like `cons-stream`). Here's a reformulation of your `delay` and `cons-stream` as macros:

```
(define-syntax delay
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ exp) (lambda () exp))))

(define-syntax cons-stream
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ a b) (cons a (delay b)))))
```